# Update dataset wth ElasticSearch Aggregation result

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to automate a features creation process for large dataset with elastic search.
I'd like to know if it is possible to create a new field in my dataset that will be the result of an aggregation.

I'm currently working on log from a network and wants to implement the moving average (the mean of a field during the past x days) of the filed "bytes_in".

After spending time reading the doc and example, I wasn't able to do so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

1. By using the [Rollup API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rollup-apis.html) you can create a job that will allow you to summarize data on the go and store it in a dedicated index.
   A detailed example can be found in this [blog article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-create-manage-and-visualize-elasticsearch-rollup-data-in-kibana).
2. By using the [Data Frame Transform API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/transform-overview.html), you can pivot your data into a new entity-centric index, [aggregate your data](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/transform-resource.html#transform-pivot-properties) in various ways and store the results in a dedicated index.

Comment: Thanks a lot !  It's exactly what I needed per se.
The problem is I can't used the basic version of elasticsearch. I can only use the oss one which doesn't contains X-Pack ...
Any other idea ?

Comment: Both of these APIs are in the [BASIC (free) version](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions). Which version of ES do you have? Why can't you use the Basic version?

Comment: Some obligation from my job unfortunately ...
I'm on a oss-6.8.3 and have to stick to it :'(

Comment: Convince your boss that it's a bad idea ;-)

Comment: Already spend hours on that and didn't go through ahah, I'm going to try to install xpack on the oss version from from the source code ;)

Comment: Good luck with that... Curious to know the real reason though