# Is there a way to index the result of an aggregation in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I'd like to know if it is possible to index the result of an aggregation in ES 6.8-oss.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Technically no.Unless you are using paid version of elastic with xpack watcher.See this link -https://discuss.elastic.co/t/re-index-aggregation-elasticsearch/75325

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick answer

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/re-indexing-an-aggregation-for-later-use/45012/3 -see this as well

Comment: Moreover if you are not on paid version ,then you have to write a custom  script may be node js ,python whatever language you prefer .That won't be a tedious task ,If you actually know how to do the aggregation correctly with top hits.

Comment: It is possible under certain conditions. See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58304705/4604579 (hint: use Rollup API and/or DF Transform API)